# Share very similar code between 2 webpages when using ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

### Explanation

I have 2 apps/webpages which use different entry points, lets call them `app1` and `app2`, which are using `entry1.js` and `entry2.js` respectively. In both apps, I use modules which are very commun between then, they are stored in a `shared` folder.

I am using OpenLayers in my project and the concept is that I have a "page 1" and a "page 2" which have lot of things in commun (the map, same feature styles, some layers, same data store logic) but also a lot of things which are different (some layers, the content of the store, the way I use the store to do things).

I currently use a file structure that looks like this:

```
entry1.js
entry2.js
app1/
    map.js
    [...]
app2/
    map.js
    [...]
shared/
    pointsLayer.js
    store.js
    styles.js
    [...]
```

In this example, `pointsLayer` uses the exact same logic between apps, the exception is the way I get the style for the Points is different.

`entry1.js`

```
import './app1/map';
import { togglePoint } from './shared/pointsLayer';

// pointsLayer is used here to bind the togglePoint function to the DOM event
$('.point-checkbox').change(function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    let eid = $this.data('eid');
    togglePoint(eid, $this.is(':checked'));
});
```

`entry2.js`

```
import './app2/map';
import { togglePoint } from './shared/pointsLayer';

// pointsLayer is used here to bind the togglePoint function to the DOM event
$('.another-point-checkbox').change(function() {
    // Bind the function to another DOM element than app1
    // [...]
    togglePoint(eid, $this.is(':checked'));
});
```

`app1/map.js` and `app2/map.js`

```
// The files looks the same because I only extracted what's relevant for you
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import pointLayer, { updatePoint } from '../shared/pointsLayer';

const map = new Map({
    layers: [pointLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View([/*...*/])
});

map.addEventListener /* ... */
// Here, on a specific map event, I call updatePoint(eid, position)
```

`shared/store.js`

```
// Here I initialise some data that come from the Global Scope
// This module allows me to share data between ES modules
export default {
    a: window.a,
    b: window.b
};
// In app1, a will be set, b will be undefined
// In app2, a will be undefined, b will be set
// a and b contain information used to set the color of a Feature Style
// That's part of the problem I'm trying to resolve
```

`shared/styles.js`

```
import { Circle, Fill, Stroke, Style, Text } from 'ol/style';
import Store from './store';

function getElementColor(eid) {
    // Here
    // I need to access Store.a[eid].color when it's app1
    // Or access Store.b[eid].color when it's app2
}

function getPointStyle(eid) {
    return new Style({
        image: new Circle({
            fill: new Fill({
                color: getElementColor(eid)
            }),
            radius: 6,
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: '#000',
                width: 2
            })
        })
    });
}

export { getPointStyle };
```

`shared/pointsLayer.js`

```
import { Feature } from 'ol';
import { Point } from 'ol/geom';
import { Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source';
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';

import Styles from './styles';

const points = {};
const source = new VectorSource();
const layer = new VectorLayer({
    source: source,
    style: new Style(null)
});

export function updatePoint(eid, position) {
    // Do stuff to update a point using the provided eid and position
    // I call the getPointStyle function from 'shared/styles.js' here
    // [...]
    points[eid].setStyle(Styles.getPointStyle(eid));
    // [...]
}

export function togglePoint(eid, visible) {
    // Do stuff to toggle a point visible or not
    // Also uses Styles.getPointStyle(eid) to set the corresponding style
}

export default layer;
```

### Problem

My problem is that everything in the `shared/pointsLayer` file can be used in both apps, but this module depends of another module which do things differently in `app1` and `app2` to get the `color` of a `Style` applied to a `Point` (see the `getElementColor` function in `shared/styles.js`).

I guess I could just make the `getElementColor` function do something like `if (Store.a === undefined) { // I am in app2 } [...]` but I'm pretty sure that's not a good way to handle this.

I thought about 2 others ideas, but I am not happy with them either.

**Idea 1**

- Set Store.app = "app1" in `app1/map.js`
- Set Store.app = "app2" in `app2/map.js`
- Check the value of Store.app in the `getElementColor` function

`map.js`

```
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import pointLayer, { updatePoint } from '../shared/pointsLayer';

// HERE
import Store from '../shared/store';
Store.app = "app1"; // Or "app2"

const map = new Map({
    layers: [pointLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View([/*...*/])
});

map.addEventListener /* ... */
// Here, on a specific map event, I call updatePoint(eid, position)
```

`shared/styles.js`

```
// [...]
function getElementColor(eid) {
    if (Store.app == 'app1') {
        // Access Store.a[eid].color
    } else {
        // Access Store.b[eid].color
    }
}
// [...]
```

**Idea 2**

- Add a function to set the "style function" inside `pointsLayer` module
- Do not rely anymore on `shared/styles.js` inside `pointsLayer` module
- Use the function in `map.js`

`shared/pointsLayer.js`

```
import { Feature } from 'ol';
import { Point } from 'ol/geom';
import { Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source';
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';

const points = {};
const source = new VectorSource();
const layer = new VectorLayer({
    source: source,
    style: new Style(null)
});

// HERE
let getPointColor = () => {};
export function setGetPointColor(fct) {
    getPointColor = fct;
}
function getPointStyle(eid) {
    return new Style({
        image: new Circle({
            fill: new Fill({
                color: getPointColor(eid)
            }),
            radius: 6,
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: '#000',
                width: 2
            })
        })
    });
}
//

export function updatePoint(eid, position) {
    // [...]
    points[eid].setStyle(getPointStyle(eid));
    // [...]
}

export function togglePoint(eid, visible) {
    // Also uses getPointStyle(eid) to set the corresponding style
}

export default layer;
```

`app1/map.js` and `app2/map.js`

```
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import pointLayer, { updatePoint, setGetPointColor } from '../shared/pointsLayer';

// HERE
setGetPointColor(function(eid) {
    let element = Store.a[eid]; // Or Store.b[eid]
    if (!element) {
        // Log, error, whatever...
        return '#000';
    }
    return element.color;
});

const map = new Map({
    layers: [pointLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View([/*...*/])
});

map.addEventListener /* ... */
// Here, on a specific map event, I call updatePoint(eid, position)
```

None of these solutions/ideas feel right to me, I'm new in using ES6 and I think maybe I'm missing some important ES module concept?
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a very long question with very nebulous goals at the end. Possibly not a [good fit for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I don't know how I can explain without giving as much information as I did

Comment: Don't use a `shared/store` at all if the data in the two applications is different. Do not use a global singleton that might have both. Instead, create separate stores in the two applications (possibly using a shared constructor, if there are similar parts), and then pass the similar parts to the shared methods.

Comment: @Bergi Let's say I have `app1/store` and `app2/store`. `shared/styles` have to choose between importing `store` from `app1` or `store` from `app2`, I don't see how I can achieve that without doing a `styles.js` file in both apps too.

Comment: @Marc No, they should not import it at all. The store instances should get passed as arguments to e.g. the `getElementColor` call from the apps

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I will dig into what you propose to see if it fits, thank you. Keep you informed asap

Comment: @Bergi If I understood, I need to pass the Store instance from `appX/map.js` to `getElementColor` in `shared/styles.js`. But I have this call architecture : `map.js` -> `pointsLayer@updatePoint` -> `styles@getPointStyle` -> `styles@getElementColor`.
Do I need to pass the Store instance all the way through these functions? It does not seem good to me.

Comment: @Marc Yes, you would. Alternatively you could have a `styles@setStore` method that stores a reference in the module scope to be available to all styles methods, or you would wrap all these modules in factory functions where you pass in the store once when creating the layer instance or styles instance. Basically you're looking for dependency injection.

Comment: Another possible solution: since these applications are completely independent and are deployed separately, you could also writee `import appStore from 'store';` (without specifying a folder) and set up your build (transpiler/bundler) so that it resolves the module identifier `store` to the respective file in app1 or app2 depending on the build configuration.

Comment: @Bergi That looks nice, I will try to look at both. I suggest you to write an answer out of all what you explained?

Comment: I might do when I find the time :-)